# MS Visual C#: Eclipse-style autocomplete for interface methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, autocomplete

When implementing interfaces in a class which implements an interface, how can I auto-complete the method signature?

For example, when using Java in Eclipse, I just start typing the name and I see a list of methods which are "missing", and I can also do this by with one mouse click. Is there something similar in Visual Studio Express?

Answer (score 5):

There may be a number of ways to do this, but what I generally do is right-click on the interface in the class declaration (below) and there's an option to "Implement Interface."

```
public class Class1 : IFace1 // <-- right-click there
{
}
```

This would create stubbed methods for everything in the interface with `NotImplementedException`s within them.

While it's not free, I also highly recommend [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) as a productivity tool for Visual Studio.  It makes things like this much quicker and more intuitive (at least in my opinion).

Comment: How is ReSharper making this (specifically) easier? How can it be easier, then pressing `Ctrl + .` or just right clicking the interface? (Not arguing, just curious... I don't actually get why are these 'productivity' plugins so expensive).

Comment: @Dampe: For this specific example, I'm not 100% sure.  I don't actually have an install of ReSharper in front of me :)  But it does provide lots of shortcut keys, auto-complete options, etc.  Personally, one of my favorite ReSharper features is that it adds a thin bar to the side of code files with color coded notifications for areas of interest (errors, warnings, potential code cleanups, etc.).  I'm not much of a salesman, really.  All I can do is suggest that you try it for yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the class and declare that it implements some abstract method, if you press ALT+SHIFT+F10 a context-menu will pop up and in there is the ability to stub all methods for the interface.  Not exactly what you're searching for, but it should solve the problem.